# XSLT passing url to asp page that does not de-escape &amp; to &, what to do?

Tags: asp.net, xml, apache-fop

I have a problem, 
I have a URL provided from a website in the form:

`http://data.dezrez.com/PictureResizer.ASP?PropertyID=99999999&amp;PhotoID=1&amp;AgentID=9999&amp;BranchID=9999&amp;width=750&amp;rotation=0`

i am then using in an XSL-FO file which is using the return code

```
<fo:external-graphic movie="auto" clip="auto" content-height="141mm" 
content-width="188mm" content-y="0mm" content-x="0mm" 
src="http://data.dezrez.com/PictureResizer.ASP?PropertyID=99999999&amp;PhotoID=1&amp;AgentID=9999&amp;BranchID=9999&amp;width=750&amp;rotation=0" 
width="188mm" height="113mm" scaling-method="resample-any-method"/>
```

however the ASP page at dezrez is not recognising the url as it cannot understand the `&amp;` and escape it to &, I have not access to their ASP page and need to know how to approach it so that it will work.

Comment: URL parsing is done by server, I think, and ASP sees params as `PropertyID=99999999` if the URL is constructed properly. Which XSL-FO renderer are you using? Can you trace the URL it sends to the server? As you posted, it should work well, since `&amp;`s are replaced with `&` by XML parser, and the renderer should see `...PropertyID=..&PhotoID=1;...`. BTW, how you found out that ASP page at dezrez is not recognizing the URL? For me shows `Error Message\nPicture does not exist\n Picture Number: 1`, as far as I understand, it recognized `PhotoID=1` and just couldn't find it.

Comment: I anonamized the ids and if i copy and paste the line with &amp; I get Error you need to provide width and rotation,  and if i post the line with just & it works, i am using a modified version of FOP and the line above is from the FO file it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesnt seem to be an XSL way to do this, so I had to write a simple servlet which de-escapes the url, calls the url, saves the returned image as a temp file and returns the aved file url to the calling process as an xml snippet

```
<xsl:variable name="mainpicurl"><xsl:text>http://www.xxxxxxx.co.uk/ImageProcessor/test?url=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="descendant-or-self::*[@id='large']/@src"/></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="mainpic" select="document($mainpicurl)"/><fo:block>
                    <xsl:variable name="mainpic" select="document($mainpicurl)"/><fo:block>
                    <xsl:call-template name="crop-scale-image">
                        <xsl:with-param name="content-width">188</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="content-height">113</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="imgurl"><xsl:value-of select="$mainpic"/></xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
```